# Multiple attachments through phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using php mailer class to send multiple attachment mails. Two error are coming my way:

**First** these two lines apear when email is sended, these errors are from class.phpmailer.php:

> Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in
>   /var/www/dev01/maiarn/class.phpmailer.php on line 1471
>
> Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in
>   /var/www/dev01/maiarn/class.phpmailer.php on line 1475 Message has
>   been sent.

**Second**
The email is sent with only one attachment, The second goes where:

```
$mail->AddAttachment("logo.jpg"); // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("logo.jpg");
```

Any Help

Comment: Can you please provide more code and format your code as code? It's hard to tell where an error might be when all you provide is one line of code that seems like it would work. The other two errors you're encountering are probably out of your hands and are just part of phpmailer that needs to be updated by that team, but it's hard to know without more code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using PHPMailer for PHP4 when you are running PHP5. If you are indeed running PHP5, make sure you have the latest PHPMailer from http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/downloads/list

As for the attachments, you are attaching the same file twice? PHPMailer is probably removing duplicates.

Comment: I am using, php 5.3.9 with phpmailer v5.1.

Comment: Try updating to the latest PHPMailer, if it doesn't fix the problem, you can just hide the errors using: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php